# How to Pass Image URL to React Router? Image is not getting Displayed in Component but image is getting passed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

> This is my Router.js File. I am trying to test if the image is
>   successfully getting loaded. but only the URL is getting displayed and
>   not the image.

```
    import ronaldo from './assets/images/ronaldo.jpg'
    import messi from './assets/images/messi.jpg'
    import Navigation from './Components/Navigation';
            class Router extends Component {

              state = {

                players:[
                  {
                    'id':1,
                    'name':'Ronaldo',
                    'image':ronaldo

                  },
                  {

                    'id':2,
                    'name':'Messi',
                    'image':messi

                  }

                ]
              }
              render(){

                return (
                  <div>
                    <Navigation />
                      <Switch>
                        <Route  exact path="/" component={App} />
                        <Route  exact path="/about" component={About} />
                        <Route  exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
                        <Route  exact path="/players" render={(props) =>  <Players  {...props} players={this.state.players} />} />
                        <Route  exact path="/players/:image" component={PlayersContainer} />
                      </Switch>
                  </div>
                ); 
              }
              }
            export default Router;
```

> I have the Links in the Players.js Component.

```
 import  React  from 'react'
        import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
        export default function Players(props){

            const renderPlayers = () => {

                return props.players.map((player) => (
                    <li><Link to={`/players/`+player.name+player.image }>  {player.name} </Link> </li>
                ))

            }
            return(
                <div>
                    <h1> Our Top Players </h1>
                    <ul>
                    {renderPlayers()}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            )

        }
```

> When i click on the Link , the PlayersContainer Component is opening,
>   but the Image is not getting loaded in the  tag.

```
import React from 'react'
        export default function PlayersContainer(props) {
            const displayPlayers = () => {
                console.log(props)    
            }

            return (
                <div>
                    {displayPlayers()}
                    <img src={`/${props.match.params.image}`} alt={props.match.params.name}></img>
                </div>
            )
        }
```

Comment: probably you can just directly try `src={props.match.params.image}` but I don't think its a correct way to pass image to be rendered in another component. Your url will hold the entire base64 data

Comment: yes as i am not using a Datababe API , i am trying to find a solution to pass the imageURL , if also thinking wheter it could be possible or not.

Comment: Alternatively you could pass the image object reference in route state, extraction would be similar to `props.location.state.image`.

Comment: i found a solution, what i did was just store the name of the image in the Object and pass it in the route. and in the Container where i am displaying the Image i just appended the name of the image to the location of the image in my assets folder. @DrewReese

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution, what i did was just store the name of the image in the Object and pass it in the route. and in the Container where i am displaying the Image i just appended the name of the image to the location of the image in my assets folder.

```
import ronaldo from './assets/images/ronaldo.jpg'
import messi from './assets/images/messi.jpg'
import Navigation from './Components/Navigation';
class Router extends Component {

  state = {

    players:[
      {
        'id':1,
        'name':'Ronaldo',
        'imageURL':'ronaldo.jpg'

      }
```

Container File.

```
import React from 'react'

export default function PlayersContainer(props) {

   const displayPlayers = () => {

       console.log(props)

    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h1> Hello </h1>
            {displayPlayers()}
            <h3> Player ID : {props.match.params.id} </h3>
            <h3> Player Name : {props.match.params.name} </h3>
            <img src={require('../../assets/images/'+props.match.params.image)}></img>

        </div>
    )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This could work if you dont use a lot of images in every route path component:

I am using React-Router-Dom and had the same problem. I am using only functional components by the way.

To fix this:

You can create separate components for each image then import like normal component in the component you want to use your image.

These components have to be outside the Router. I recommend using Styled Components in order to make it easy to change any css related to your images